# How to change Paypal's checkout shipping address dynamically?

Tags: angular, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to implement the paypal checkout in my platform. I already saw the API's documentation and I tryied various ways they said to do it, but I couldn't make it for some reason. Right now my code is in snipped.

```
payment: (data, actions) => {
  return actions.payment.create({
    address_details:{
      street_number: "123",
      street_name: "Test address"       
    },
    address_portable:{
      postal_code:"4590-555",
      country_code:"PT"
    },
    payment: {
      transactions: [
        { 
          amount: { 
            total: this.TotalPrice, 
            currency: 'EUR' 
          } 
        },
      ],
      note_to_payer: "Contact us for any questions on your order.",
    }
  });
}
```

For you have an idea what I wanna change, please take a look at the next image.
[image: Shipping address]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this was asked a while ago. I've had a similar problem and spent a lot of time trying to work out how the API all works. The PayPal doc [here][1] isn't very clear. The solution that worked for me was to warp the details inside an `address` object nested in a `payer` object:

```
payment: (data, actions) => {
  return actions.payment.create({
    payer : {
    address :{
    address_details:{
      street_number: "123",
      street_name: "Test address"       
    },
    address_portable:{
      postal_code:"4590-555",
      country_code:"PT"
    }
    }
    },
    payment: {
      transactions: [
        { 
          amount: { 
            total: this.TotalPrice, 
            currency: 'EUR' 
          } 
        },
      ],
      note_to_payer: "Contact us for any questions on your order.",
    }
  });
}


  [1]: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-payer
```